# Рандомное перемешивание блоков при обновлении страницы

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, случайные-числа

Нужно сделать так, чтобы при каждой перезагрузке страницы блоки рандомно перемешивались. Например, есть 3 `div'a` и нужно, чтобы они каждый раз перемешивались.
Приведите, пожалуйста, пример кода на **PHP** или **JS**

Comment: Можно сделать на PHP, можно сделать на JS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте вот так. Решение через jQuery

```js
(function(){
  $(function(){
    var $divs = $('.rand div');
    var arr = [];
    $divs.each(function(){
      arr.push($(this).detach());
    });
    arr.sort(function(a, b){
      return Math.random() - 0.5;
    });
    for (var index in arr) {
      $('.rand').append(arr[index]);
    }
  });
})();
```

```css
* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}

.rand div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 33%;
  height: 100px;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="rand">
  <div class="red"></div>
  <div class="green"></div>
  <div class="blue"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    $array = ['<div class="1">1</div>','<div class="2">2</div>','<div class="3">3</div>'];
    shuffle($array);
    foreach($array as $value){
        echo $value;
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
   $box[] = '<div class="block">блок 1</div>';
   $box[] = '<div class="block">блок 2</div>';
   $box[] = '<div class="block">блок 3</div>';
   $box[] = '<div class="block">блок 4</div>';

   shuffle($box);
   echo $box[0];
?>
```

В данному случае у тебя будет при каждом обновлении первый блок всегда разный вылазить.

вот инфа с офф источника про данную функцию http://php.net/manual/ru/function.shuffle.php

Comment: ссылку на ман можете добавить прямо в ответ, нажав "править".